# Find the shortest path between 2 nodes with RedisGraph

Tags: redis, redisgraph

I have simple nodes with integer ids. I just want to find the shortest path between to nodes given their id. I tried :

```
GRAPH.QUERY mygraph "MATCH p=(startnode)-[*]-(endnode) WHERE ID(startnode)=2 AND ID(endnode)=1 RETURN p"
```

or something with algo.BFS but no example is given

```
GRAPH.QUERY mygraph "CALL algo.BFS source-node YIELD redisnodes,redisedges"
```

But I didn't succeed. Is this feature available ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one option (a bit expensive)

```
MATCH p = (a{v:1})-[*]-(c {v:2}) WITH collect(p) AS paths, min(length(p)) AS min_len RETURN [p in paths WHERE length(p) = min_len | p][0]
```

Another option would have to be `algo.BFS` but it will require additional client side processing.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. What is "v" ? it is not an attribute of the nodes. And it seems that this feature will come with version 2.4 : https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph/issues/440

Comment: @JeffProd Correct, the shortestPath is planned for the 2.4 release, most likely in H1 of next year